# Don't see Local Modifications function

Tags: google-chrome

As I know from this tutrial https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/local-modifications I must have Local Modifications in Google Chrome Development Tools, when clicking right mouse button on window of Source → Filesiystem → myfile.js. But I haven't it. Can you say, is it ok?

I am using version 65.0.3325.181 on Windows 7.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking pls edit your question. for forthur information reed https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't see "local modification" feature. Here this quastion is described in detail https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/local-modifications